# How can I change the opacity of a certain text by clicking another div?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show a line of text when the "Get in Touch" button is clicked on a mock website, like so:

[image]

I have the current opacity of the submit message at 0 so it is not visible, but how would I be able to get it's opacity to 1 when the submit link about is clicked, using css or jQuery?

Comment: No forms are actually being submitted when clicking the button, this is just a mock up website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brain seems to have not been working today... this was not working for me because javascript was not enabled on my computer. The code was very simple.

```
$(".button").on("click", function(){
  $(".feedback").css("opacity", "1");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a mockup:

```js
$("#submitButton").on("click", function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#thanks").fadeIn( 800 ); // Show Thanks
});
```

```css
 #thanks{ display:none; }      /* Hide Thanks */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Your message:<br>
<textarea></textarea><br>
<a href="javascript:;" id="submitButton"><b>Get in touch</b></a>
<div id="thanks">Thanks for your inquiry!</div>
```

---

Usually you would use a `success` AJAX event before doing so (since I see you're probably submitting a form)

CSS (Hide Tthanks):

```
#thanks{ display:none; }
```

jQuery (show Thanks on Success):

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/mail.php', // or whoever sends stuff
        type: "POST",
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {
           console.log( response ); // Whatever server echoed on success 
           $("#thanks").show(); // Show THANKS OK?
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            console.log(a, b, c);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the text, just change the opacity of the element, either by changing the opacity css property or through jquery animate.

```
<style>
span
{
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
<input type="text">
<button>
Get In Touch
</button>
<span>Thanks for your inquiry</span>
<script>
$("button").click(function()
{
  $('span').animate({ opacity: 1 },1000);
});
</script>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3mb8ep19/2/